# Android close testing - getting error of "Your device is not compatible with this version"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play

I have uploaded app on store in close testing.
I've become the tester of the app, but when I try to download app from my phone, it is saying me that "Your device is not compatible with this version"

I have some features that i want to test before publishing it on store for other users, so i have created one track with adding email id in testers in closed testing.

After track is released i have become the tester for the project wit WebLink and then i tried to download app from store, Then it is saying me that "Your device is not compatible with this version". It is showing my app name with (beta).

I've checked it is available for my country, Android version is also compatible with my phone. Also I have checked all the tester's team in Internal App Sharing Options.

It will be really helpful if someone can help me to sort my problem.

Here is my Manifest file snippets:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="31"
        tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="31"
        tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        tools:targetApi="s" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Please include the AndroidManifest.xml file and which device you are also trying to install it on. There are certain features that can be required by the manifest file that will limit what devices it can be installed on. Another thing to check on is whether or not the device in question is listed within the supported devices in the `Device Catalog` section in the play console.

Comment: @undermark5 I am able to run app on my device through Android Studio, but when i try to download app from play store i'm receiving error. Updated answer with Manifest file

Comment: hmm, well none of those `uses-feature` blocks would prevent it from installing via the play store AFAIK, however, you also didn't seem to include what device you are trying to install on. You can check on the play console whether or not the device you are trying to install on is included in the supported devices in the `Device Catalog` section as I mentioned above.

Comment: @undermark5 I am using oppo A9 2020 and i have checked it in device catalog and it says partially supported.

Comment: Yes i have checked and you were right some of the service which third-party sdk is using is not supported in my phone, so that is why it is not compatible with my phone. Thanks @undermark5 for your help.

Comment: If you've found the solution to your question, consider posting an answer describing the specifics of it and how you came to find it. This will help others that come in the future.